# Using Regular Expressions to Extract specific Values in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have several strings in the rough form:

```
String s = "Rendering content from websiteNAme using user agent userAgentNameWithSpaces ; for user username ; at time someTime";
```

I want to extract the values for websiteName, userAgentNameWithSpaces, username and someTime.
I have tried the following code.

```
private static final Pattern USER_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("for user.*;");
final Matcher matcher = USER_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(line); 
matcher.find() ? Optional.of(matcher.group(group)) : Optional.empty();
```

It returns the whole string " for user username" after that I have to replace the for user string with empty string to get the user name.
However, I want to know if there is regex to just get the username directly?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also is your `String` format the same every time?

Comment: Yes, I tried following code.
private static final Pattern USER_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("for user.*;");
final Matcher matcher = USER_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(line); 
matcher.find() ? Optional.of(matcher.group(group)) : Optional.empty();

It returns the whole string " for user username" after that I have to replace the for user string with empty string to get the user name.
However, I want to know if there is regex to just get the username directly?

Comment: Edit your question with the contents instead.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex groups:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("for user (\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The pair of parenthesis `(` and `)` forms a group that can be obtained by the matcher using `group` method (as it's the first parenthesis, it's group 1).

`\w` means a "word character" (letters, numbers and `_`) and `+` means "one or more ocurrences". So `\w+` means basically "a word" (assuming your username has only these characters). PS: note that I had to escape `\`, so the resulting expression is `\\w+`.

The ouput of this code is:

> username

---

If you want to match all the values (websiteName, userAgentNameWithSpaces and so on), you could do the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Rendering content from (.*) using user agent (.*) ; for user (.*) ; at time (.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
}
```

The output will be:

```
websiteNAme
userAgentNameWithSpaces
username
someTime
```

Note that if `userAgentNameWithSpaces` contains spaces, `\w+` won't work (because `\w` doesn't match spaces), so `.*` will work in this case.

---

But you can also use  `[\w ]+` - the brackes `[]` means "any of the characters inside me", so `[\w ]` means "a word character, or a space" (note that there's a space between `w` and `]`. So the code would be (testing with a username with spaces):

```
String s = "Rendering content from websiteNAme using user agent userAgent Name WithSpaces ; for user username ; at time someTime";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Rendering content from (.*) using user agent ([\\w ]+) ; for user (.*) ; at time (.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
}
```

And the output will be:

```
websiteNAme
userAgent Name WithSpaces
username
someTime
```

---

Note: you can test if the groups were matched before calling `matcher.group(n)`. The method `matcher.groupCount()` returns how many groups were matched (because if you call `matcher.group(n)` and group **n** is not available, you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 
Now, I am using this expression to match userAgentWithSpaces. Lemme know if this is right. 

Pattern.compile("using user agent ([\\w*\\s*]*)");

Comment: How about this. 
Pattern TEMPLATE_LOG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
                "Rendering content from (.*)using user agent (.*) ; for user (.*) ; at time (.*)$");
time = System.out.println(matcher.group(4).trim());
userName = System.out.println(matcher.group(3).trim());

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
String s = "Rendering content from websiteNAme using user agent userAgentNameWithSpaces ; for user username ; at time someTime";
Pattern USER_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<=for user).*?(?=;)");
final Matcher matcher = USER_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(s);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(0).trim());
```

Output:

> username

Comment: Worked like a charm. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can replace `.*?` with `[^;]*` or even `[^;]*+` to save some match attempts.